# Unexpected identifier with ejs

Tags: javascript, node.js, ejs

Lately I feel like I have been fighting with the Ejs templating engine. I am getting and unexpected identifier that I cant seem to figure out why that's the case.

**Error**

```
SyntaxError: path\views\main.ejs:34
```

which is the following line of code from main.ejs

```
<%- include('partials/comments'); %>
```

Then the error message continues as follows,

```
Unexpected identifier in path\views\partials\comments.ejs while compiling ejs
```

**Relevant lines from main.ejs**

```
<div class="col-sm-4">
    <%- include('partials/stats'); %>
    <%- include('partials/popular'); %>
    <%- include('partials/comments'); %>
</div>
```

**partials/comments.ejs**

```
<div class="panel-body">
    <ul class="media-list">
        <% for(int i = 0; i < sidebar.comments.length; i++){ %>
            <li class="media">
                <a class="pull-left" href="/images/<%- sidebar.comments[i].image.uniqueId %>">
                    <img class="media-object" width="45" height="45" src="/public/upload/ <%- sidebar.comments[i].image.filename  %>">
                </a>
                <div class="media-body"><%- sidebar.comments[i].comment %>
                    <br/>
                    <strong class="media-heading"> <%- sidebar.comments[i].name %></strong>
                    <small class="text-muted"> <%- timeago(sidebar.comments[i].timestamp) %></small>
                </div>
            </li>
        <% } %>
    </ul>
</div>
```

What causes this error and how do I solve it?

I Think that the problem is with ejs and not the `Viewmodel` being sent to the `comments.ejs` template. Just in case, I have listed these functions below.

**What the viewModel looks like**

```
const ViewModel = {
    image:{
        uniqueId: 1,
        title: 'Sample Image 1',
        description: 'This is a sample.',
        filename: 'sample1.jpg',
        Views: 0,
        likes: 0,
        timestamp: Date.now()
    },
    comments: [
        {
            image_id: 1,
            email: 'test@testing.com',
            name: 'Test Tester',
            gravatar: 'http://lorempixel.com/75/75/animals/1',
            comment: 'This is a test comment...',
            timestamp: Date.now()
        }, {
            image_id: 1,
            email: 'test@testing.com',
            name: 'Test Tester',
            gravatar: 'http://lorempixel.com/75/75/animals/2',
            comment: 'Another followup comment!',
            timestamp: Date.now()
        }
    ],
    state:'Images',
};
```

**image.js**

```
const sidebar = require('../helpers/sidebar');
const path = require('path');

module.exports = {
    index(req, res) {
        sidebar(ViewModel, (ViewModel) => {
            res.render('main', ViewModel);
        });
    }
}
```

**sidebar**

```
const Stats = require('./stats')
const Images = require('./images')
const Comments = require('./comments');

module.exports = (ViewModel, callback) => {
    ViewModel.sidebar = {
        stats: Stats(),
        popular: Images.popular(),
        comments: Comments.newest()
    };
    callback(ViewModel);
};
```

**comments.js**

```
module.exports = {
    newest() {
        let comments = [
            {
                image_id: 1,
                email: 'test@testing.com',
                name: 'Test Tester',
                gravatar: 'http://lorempixel.com/75/75/animals/1',
                comment: 'This is a test comment...',
                timestamp: Date.now(),
                image: {
                    uniqueId: 1,
                    title: 'Sample Image 1',
                    description: '',
                    filename: 'sample1.jpg',
                    Views: 0,
                    likes: 0,
                    timestamp: Date.now
                }
            }, 
            {
                image_id: 1,
                email: 'test@testing.com',
                name: 'Test Tester ',
                gravatar: 'http: //lorempixel.com/75/75/animals/2',
                comment: 'Another followup comment!',
                timestamp: Date.now(),
                image: {
                     uniqueId: 1,
                     title: 'Sample Image 1',
                     description: '',
                     filename: 'sample1.jpg',
                     Views: 0,
                     likes: 0,
                     timestamp: Date.now
                }
            }
        ];
        return comments;
    }
};
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error message:

```
Unexpected identifier in partials/comments.ejs while compiling ejs
```

Tells us that the error is in comments.ejs, and sure enough:

```
<% for(int i = 0; i < sidebar.comments.length; i++){ %>
```

Specifically, `int` should be `let` or `var`.